# concatenating EL string to access items in for each loop

Tags: java, jsp, session, jstl

From Java code, I am creating several session objects dynamically.
Eg: action_**1**,action_**2** action_**3**.

All these objects contain List of items.These need to looped in JSTL for each loop. The problem is I can't hard code the JSP to have the session object names, for eg:

```
 <c:forEach items="${action_1}" var="view_actio">
   <c:out value="${view_actio.display_name}"></c:out>
 </c:forEach>
```

I have the suffix numbers in another session "view" which can be accessed as `${view.view_id}`. I've tried concatenating in the following ways,

**1st attempt:**

```
<c:forEach items="action_${view.view_id}" var="view_actio">
  <c:out value="${view_actio.display_name}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

> Error: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'display_name' not
>   found on type java.lang.String

**2nd attempt:**

```
<c:set var="s" scope="session" value="action_${view.view_id}"></c:set> 
    <c:out value="${s}"></c:out>            
<c:forEach items="${s}" var="view_actio">
    <c:out value="${view_actio.display_name}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

> Errorjavax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'display_name' not
>   found on type java.lang.String

**3rd attempt:**

```
<c:forEach items="action_<c:out value="${view.view_name}"></c:out>" var="view_actio">
    <c:out value="${view_actio.display_name}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

> Error:org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/SMGT.jsp (line: 56,
>   column: 47) Unterminated <c:forEach tag

**4th attempt:**

```
<c:set var="s" scope="session" value="action_${view.view_id}"></c:set> 
 <c:forEach items="${requestScope['s']}" var="view_actio">
    <c:out value="${view_actio.display_name}"></c:out>
 </c:forEach>
```

I have no idea what this does, I just picked this up from some other answer. However, this one neither produced output nor gave error. So its no use !

Basically, you get the idea. I need to access the elements inside the `action_1` or `action_2`. But I am unable to form it in JSP. I tried even more crazier things but cant post everything.

Does anyone know how to get this to work ?